# how to handle both RecyclerView on item click listener for its rows and the views inside it

Tags: android

I have recyclerView which contains some text view and 2 image view.

I would like to do a task when user clicks on each row and another task when user clicks on each of image views .. but I can only handle one of them at the same time.

Now if I set `recylerview.addOnItemTouchListener` I can't handle images views onclicks with setting on `clicklistener` for them in the adapter because when user clicks on image view the row's click listener will trigger.

Below code is my class for handling recycler view items

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
```

and this is my holder inside adapter

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_word = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_show);
            tv_english = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_english_show);
            tv_translation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tranlation_show);
            tv_numbershow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_numershow);
            fav = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_fav);
            more = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_more);
            fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext,"show some text for test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

I appreciate any help for my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create Interface in you adapter class.

```
 public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        public interface ClickListener {
            void ItemClicked(View v, int position);
        }
```

Declare the object on top like this:

```
ClickListener clickListener;

holder.view.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener( 
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.ItemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
);
```

Implement this interface in class and intialize the clicklistener where you are setting adapter to recyclerview.

```
 adapter.setClickListener(this);
```

When you will implement this in class you will get following method:

```
 @Override
    public void ItemClicked(View v, int position) {

    }
```

Apply switch case from `v.getId()` you can handle as many click listeners you need to implement.

Comment: hello Preetika Kaur tanx for answering to my question i got the idea of it but i did not get where shoud i declare holder.view.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener( 
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.ItemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
); in my adapter

Comment: yes you have to add this on the views in your adapter on bindviewholder() Kindly upvote the answer as well if it helps you

Comment: tanx again bro i upvoted your ansewer as soon as i saw it but i dont know why it dosen show it :( it says votes cast by thos with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change publicy displayed post score  ; ty any wayy

Comment: I am not bro.. I am a girl... I have increased your reputation its thirteen now you have to increase your reputation upto 15 then upvote it....